# Eclipse C++ Not Debugging

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

I am using Eclipse Juno, minGW and CDT. I have a tiny little HellowWorld program that I have written. It builds and runs just fine through Eclipse. However, when I try and debug, I get prompted to move to the Debug perspective (which I accept), the following text is displayed in console

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[New Thread 10056.0x265c]
[New Thread 10056.0x1578]
[New Thread 10056.0xe28]
```

And that's it. The "Debug" tab where you would see the application and the thread tree is blank. None of the debug stepping buttons are active. It appears to not even be executing my application as my cout lines aren't even coming through (let alone execution stopping at a breakpoint).
As I said, if I just "Run as" the application runs just fine. The problem appears only while debugging. I have cleaned, rebooted verified my minGW PATH entries. The only partial lead I have is on the "Executables" tab, I see my .exe file but I do not see any source files here. I don't know if that is correct or not.

Here is what I see:
[Eclipse Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsZrP.png)